# Can you use the Nether Scroll of Azumar again to resummon the golem after it dies?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items

Since the [*Nether Scroll of Azumar*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/3001257-nether-scroll-of-azumar) (*Candlekeep Mysteries*, p. 210) is not a consumable item, could you keep using the scroll to resummon a golem if your current golem dies?

Would you need to wait 30 days between summons, provided you always succeed on your ability check?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### You will have to restudy the scroll and pass the Intelligence (Arcana) check again.

Notably, the [*Nether Scroll of Azumar*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/3001257-nether-scroll-of-azumar) is not a consumable magic item:

> Unlike most scrolls, a Nether Scroll of Azumar is not a consumable magic item.

However, having successfully studied the scroll once does not change how you interact with the scroll in the future. The scroll's description states (emphasis mine):

> *When you gain the scroll’s benefits*, a stone golem magically appears in an unoccupied space within 60 feet of you and acts as your ally.

To gain the scroll's benefits, you must complete this task:

> It takes 30 days of concentrated study—at least 8 hours per day—to attempt to understand this scroll. After completing this study, you must make a DC 25 Intelligence (Arcana) check. If this check fails, you take 16d10 psychic damage, and you can attempt the check again after another 30 days of concentrated study.
>
> When you succeed on the check, you gain the following benefits:
>
> [...]

Even if you have studied it before, you must study it again to gain its benefits a second time.  In summary, you must first gain the scrolls benefits to summon the golem, you must pass the DC 25 Intelligence (Arcana) check to gain the scroll's benefits, and you must study the scroll for 30 days before you can attempt the check. And nothing in the item description indicates that having succeeded before changes how this process works.

Comment: The problem I see with this answer is that, after passing the arcana check, the character "understands" the scroll. So why would they need to study it again? It also only says you can reattempt if you fail, not if you succeed.

Comment: Because....magic? It is a bit of a hole, but without assuming you need to re-study, it becomes an infinite immediate golem creator. Which doesn't seem right! As a DM, I would probably say that the scroll subtly changes each time its used.

Comment: @AllanMills the description presents the conditions for gaining benefits, and gives no indication that those conditions are in any way changed after they have been met the first time. Ergo, if you meet the conditions again, you can gain the benefits again.

Comment: @AllanMills you are probably right, and I would expect a DM to rule in some middle ground rather than stick to this seemingly raw but quite boring reading. Always having a golem around doesn't sound that powerful at the time you might get this scroll.

Answer (score 1):

### You can only obtain the golem once

The *Nether scroll of Azumar* states that the following happens when you succeed on the Arcana check to use it:

> When you succeed on the check, you gain the following
> benefits:
>
> - Your Intelligence score increases by 2, to a maximum
>   of 22. **Once you gain this benefit, you can't
>   use this scroll to increase your Intelligence again**.
> - You gain advantage on saving throws against
>   spells and other magical effects.
>
> **When you gain the scroll’s benefits**, a stone golem
> magically appears in an unoccupied space within 60
> feet of you and acts as your ally.

There are two benefits. You only can gain the first benefit once. As the golem only appears when you gain the scroll's **benefits** (plural), **the golem will not appear again, as it is impossible to gain both benefits again**.

One even could argue that, because you already gained advantage on saving throws against spells, and that is permanent, you cannot "gain" that again either, because you already have it so in effect you gain nothing for your saves on reading the scroll again (unless you lost it to some other cause somehow). In this reading, you get neiter of the two benefits again if you reread the scroll.

Either way, it is not possible to gain the benefits again upon rereading, and therefor no new golem should be generated.

As a side benefit, this also avoids the issue of why you would need to spend another 30 days of re-reading the scroll to understand it, if you already have understood it, which is rather unsatisfactory in my mind.